# How to write a C# List to CSV with CsvHelper package

Tags: c#, .net, list, csv, csvhelper

I have a simple Console Application that contains a list of 3 users in Program.cs. Within Program.cs I want to call a method in `FileOperations.cs`.

First my `Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using CsvHelper;

namespace GimpiesConsoleOOcsvListUI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create user default instances
            User user0 = new User("Beheer", "beheer@gimpies.nl", "123");
            User user1 = new User("Inkoop", "inkoop@gimpies.nl", "123");
            User user2 = new User("Verkoop", "verkoop@gimpies.nl", "123");

            // List of users (with a list you can add, get and remove items in the list)
            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            users.Add(user0);
            users.Add(user1);
            users.Add(user2);

            // Create login instance
            LoginManager loginMgr = new LoginManager();

            Start:
            // Welcome message
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to GimpiesTerminal! Choose 1 to login or 2 to register:");

            // Get input from user
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            bool successfull = false;

            while (!successfull)
            {
                if(input == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your username:");
                    string username = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your password:");
                    string password = Console.ReadLine();

                    foreach (User user in users)
                    {
                        if (username == user.UserName && password == user.PassWord)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You have successfully logged in !!!");
                                Console.ReadLine();
                                successfull = true;
                            break;  
                            }
                    }
                        if (!successfull)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Your username or password is incorrect, try again !!!");
                            }
                }
                else if (input == "2")
                {
                        // Get user input
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter your username:");
                        string username = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter your email:");
                        string email = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter your password:");
                        string password = Console.ReadLine();

                        // Create fresh instance to save input in memory
                        User user = new User(username, email, password);

                        // Adds the user to the excisting list
                        users.Add(user);
                        
                        successfull = true;
                        goto Start;
                }
                else if (input == "3")
                {
                    // Here I want to call the method from FileOperations.cs to write the List here to a CSV file.
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try again !!!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            // // Loop over stored users within instances inside the list where users are added
            // foreach (User user in users)
            // {
            
            //     if(loginMgr.Login(user))
            //     {
            //         // Login successfull
            //         Console.WriteLine("Login user " + user.UserName);

            //     }
            //     else
            //     {
            //         // Not successfull

            //     }
            // }  
            
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `FileOperations.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using CsvHelper;

namespace GimpiesConsoleOOcsvListUI
{
    public class FileOperations
    {
        // Handles CRUD within CSV files and able to save them
        public void SaveToCSV(User user)
        {
            using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
                csvWriter.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                csvWriter.Configuration.AutoMap<User>();

                csvWriter.WriteHeader<User>();
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(user);

                writer.Flush();
                var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I get the following errors at line 16 of `FileOperations.cs`:

StreamWriter writer
Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.IO.StreamWriter` to `CsvHelper.ISerializer`

And line 23:

User user
Argument 1: cannot convert from `GimpiesConsoleOOcsvListUI.User` to `System.Collections.IEnumerable`

I'm new to C# so I hope you don't mind if it is a simple to solve problem! :-)

Comment: I don't understand the flow of your code; you have a list of users you want to save, and you have a class with a method  that saves only a single user into a memory stream (so not to disk) and then promptly throws the memory stream away so nothing will be saved anywhere. Might be worth going through your code and commenting the algorithm so you have a native language set of steps of what you need to do to achieve the goal, and then you can assess whether the c# under the comment really does what the comment says; "write in English(/your native thinking language) first then translate to c#"

Comment: Do not use `goto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following piece of code if you want to serialize a single user object and display its serialized header and values:

```
public void SaveToCSV(List<User> users)
{
    var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = true,
        Delimiter = ",",
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    };

    using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfig))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(users);

        writer.Flush();
        var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

It is using a simple `StringWriter` instance needed by the library's `CsvWriter` and is using `InvariantCulture` info for content serialization. The third parameter `leaveOpen` must be set to `true` in this case because you're interested in the content of the `StringWriter` within the scope of the `using` block. Last but not least, you're currently passing a single instance of `User` so you have to call `WriteRecord` method instead of `WriteRecords`.

If you want to write it to the actual file though, you have to do it a bit differently:

```
public void SaveToCSV(List<User> users)
{
    var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = true,
        Delimiter = ",",
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    };

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"path\to\your\file.csv"))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfig))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(users);
    }
}
```

You don't need to call `Flush` in the second example because the end of `using` block calls it for you and you're not interested in the CSV content within its scope.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your effort. I’ll give this a go as well. My next step was indeed writing to a CSV file. I’ll get back when I tried all of your tips.

Comment: I tried to write the csv file and it works! The only problem I have now is that the first entry of the list is written next to the header items. So it becomes something like this:

Name ; Email ; Password ; Admin ; admin@admin.com ; 123
Sales ; sales@admin.com ; 123
Purchase ; purchase@admin.com ; 123

Maybe you know how to solve this?

Comment: I made a temporary solutions with an empty first user:



`// Create user default instances
            User user0 = new User("", "", "");
            User user1 = new User("Beheer", "beheer@gimpies.nl", "123");
            User user2 = new User("Inkoop", "inkoop@gimpies.nl", "123");
            User user3 = new User("Verkoop", "verkoop@gimpies.nl", "123");`

Comment: The reason why the header row and first data row are combined is because the code in the above example is wrong - you don't need `csvWriter.WriteHeader<User>();` in combination with `csvWriter.WriteRecords(users);`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the errors because you are passing the wrong parameter types in both cases.
`CsvWriter` does not have a constructor which takes only one parameter being a `TextWriter`.  I am not very familiar with this library, but I believe it may have done in the past. I suspect you have copied your code from previous examples on the internet, which are out of date.

The simple way to get around this is to add two more parameters thus:

```
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false))
```

The second error is because `CsvWriter.WriteRecords` expects an `IEnumerable` parameter, not a single instance.  To fix this, you need to pass it your `List<User>`, so the whole code becomes:

```
public void SaveToCSV(List<User> users)
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false))
    {
        csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
                
        csvWriter.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
        csvWriter.Configuration.AutoMap<User>();

        csvWriter.WriteHeader<User>();
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(users);

        writer.Flush();
        var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and explanation.  I’ll give this a try soon. When it works I’ll get back to this thread. Also after the solution I’ll change it to actually save the informatie to a CSV file.

Comment: Jonathan: Thanks to your example I made some steps. Also msmolcic thanks! Both of your feedback and examples made it al work. Now some fine tuning left! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Due to [this](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1653) change in `csvhelper`, the given examples won't work.

The updated code of @Jonathn would look like -

```
public void SaveToCSV(List<User> users)
    {
        var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            Delimiter = ",",
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };

        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfig))
        {
            csvWriter.WriteHeader<User>();
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(users);

            writer.Flush();
            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```